# Setting content size for a modal popover storyboard segue on iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have some modal segues in the iPad version of my app, and I'm wondering where / how I tell them what size to display the content? If I was pushing the view controller programmatically I could do this with `setContentSize` or similar – how/where do I do this when segues are being used?

I'm trying the following but the transitioned view appears full-screen, not in the size I specify – why is that?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
#pragma unused (sender)
    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[SignUpViewController class]]) {
        SignUpViewController *signUp = (SignUpViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
        signUp.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about setting popover size directly instead of a view controller size?

```
UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *popoverSegue = (id)segue;
popoverSegue.popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
```

I believe, at this point the popover is already created and resized to a previous value of `contentSizeForViewInPopover`.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but unfortunately as I had a non-Pad-specific storyboard, I didn't have access to the `popover` segue type.